# Mysql error #1064 when trying to create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a MySQL trigger but don't know why error `#1064` occurs. Here is the full error message:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR select (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_' at line 22`

`Line #22` is `close cur;`

and here is what I've done so far:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER business_popularity_trigger_after_review_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_reviews FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE data_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE businessId, reviewId, dealId, businessServiceId INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE businessPopularity INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE popularity_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select tbl_reviews.review_id, tbl_reviews.deal_id, deals.deal_id, deals.business_service_id, business_services.business_service_id, business_services.business_id from tbl_reviews INNER JOIN deals ON deals.deal_id = new.deal_id INNER JOIN business_services ON business_services.business_service_id = deals.business_service_id  
where tbl_reviews.review_id = new.review_id 
group by business_services.business_id;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET data_finished = 1;
OPEN cur;
    get_data: LOOP
        fetch cur into reviewId, dealId, businessServiceId, businessId;
        IF data_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_data;
        END IF;
   END LOOP get_data;
close cur;
DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR select (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_reviews.vote_value)) from tbl_reviews INNER JOIN business_services ON business_services.business_id = businessId INNER JOIN deals ON deals.business_service_id = business_services.business_service_id where deals.deal_is_deleted = 'N' and tbl_reviews.review_is_deleted = 'N' and tbl_reviews.review_status = 'Y';
set data_finished = 0;
IF businessId > 0 THEN
    OPEN popularity_cur;
        get_popularity: LOOP
            fetch popularity_cur into businessPopularity;
            IF data_finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_popularity;
            END IF;
       END LOOP get_popularity;
    close popularity_cur;
Update business 
set business.business_popularity = businessPopularity  
where business.business_id = businessId;
END IF;
delimiter;
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct delimiter `//` at the end and close the `BEGIN ... END` construction. So change last lines to:

```
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

**UPDATE** Since you use aggregating functions `SUM`, `COUNT` you need `GROUP BY` statement. So try this way:

```
DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_reviews.vote_value)) 
  FROM tbl_reviews 
  INNER JOIN business_services 
  ON business_services.business_id = tbl_reviews.businessId 
  INNER JOIN deals 
  ON deals.business_service_id = business_services.business_service_id 
    AND deals.deal_is_deleted = 'N' 
  WHERE tbl_reviews.review_is_deleted = 'N' 
    AND tbl_reviews.review_status = 'Y'
  GROUP BY tbl_reviews.businessId;
```

I did some optimization and you had wrong condition `business_services.business_id = businessId` so I did change to `business_services.business_id = tbl_reviews.businessId`.

**NOTE** Probably that wasn't a mistake and you need that `business_services.business_id = businessId` condition. But even if you need that you should use one condition for `JOIN` and another one to filter. so it could be like:

```
INNER JOIN business_services 
  ON business_services.business_id = tbl_reviews.business_id
    AND business_services.business_id = businessId
```

**UPDATE 2** According to the screenshot with your database schema your query could be like:

```
DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_reviews.vote_value)) 
  FROM tbl_reviews 
  INNER JOIN deals 
  ON  tbl_reviews.deal_id = deals.deal_id 
    AND deals.deal_is_deleted = 'N' 
  INNER JOIN business_services 
  ON business_services.business_service_id  = deals.business_service_id 
  WHERE tbl_reviews.review_is_deleted = 'N' 
    AND tbl_reviews.review_status = 'Y'
  GROUP BY deals.business_service_id;
```

Comment: I changed as you said, but still getting same error i.e. ```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR select (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_' at line 22```

Comment: ok. I have another question then, why do you use `FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3...` instead of `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Well, ```INNER JOIN / FULL JOIN``` is same as ```FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3...```. I think that should not create any issue.

Comment: no it is not the same. when you `JOIN` you show real connection rules between tables. it is easy to see, easy to debug, easy to understand. I am not sure what mysql server does with your `FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3...`

Comment: I read updated answer and that is not the way I need it. In  ```business_services.business_id = businessId``` condition ```businessId``` is a variable I **declared**  on line# 6. Second, ```GROUP BY``` will not work here as we are calculating average rating (second cursor query) of a business. So, to calculate average rating we must **sum()** all vote values (ranges 0.0 - 5.0) and divide them by total number of votes. I hope you understand. Let me know if you need tables schema.

Comment: No I don't need it yet. `GROUP BY` will work since you set `businessId` as filter - it will return 1 row so there is no conflict with your requirements.

Comment: No, I don't need 1 row. As ```business``` table has no direct relation with ```tbl_reviews```. Actually, the scenario is, user creates a business by adding business details, addresses and selecting services/categories (stored in ```business_services``` table). Now, each service/category may have 0/many deals (stored in ```deals``` table) and a deal may have 0/many reviews (stored in ```tbl_reviews``` table) with rating i.e. **vote_value** column. Having said that, what I want is to calculate average rating of 1 business at a time.

Comment: that means you need 1 row. And if *business table has no direct relation with tbl_reviews* (do you mean `business_services` table?) you can't join them in proper way. those tables must have relations to other tables in your query - so you have to change `ON` rule but you can't ignore that. And mysql can't invent the rule for you

Comment: Please take a look at [table schema](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5J4KN9eqkrZLTlaeTZ2R1NWSG8/view?usp=sharing) image. It will help you better understand what my question is.

Comment: Query in **Update 2** is fine and exactly does what I need :). But, unfortunately I am still unable to create trigger. Getting same error **#1064** ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE popularity_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT (sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(' at line 22```

Comment: :-) listen. to find the bug try to do this way. remove this `DECLARE ...SELECT` from your procedure just for a moment and maybe everything that comes after till the `END`. this way we can be sure that the problem is with this query. If it works. then add the simple one like `SELECT id FROM mytable` so we can be sure that problem is with oure select query or not. And if yes - play with your select - line by line, to figure out which line brings the error. By the way I would prefer to give a name to the field  `(sum(tbl_reviews.vote_value)/count(tbl_reviews.vote_value)) as my_colunm_name`